# Cannot delete the selected item from listview (values in sqlite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to delete a selected item from list view. The values are stored in database. I tried it in sqlite. How to delete the values present in database and update the listview

```
  private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";


        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

       var stt=con.QueryAsync<list>("delete from list where list1='"+list_view.SelectedItem+"'");
       con.DeleteAsync(stt);

       update();

    }

    public async void update()
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        List<list> mylist = await con.QueryAsync<list>("select * from list");
        if (mylist.Count != 0)
        {
            list_view.ItemsSource = mylist;
            list_view.DisplayMemberPath = "list1";
        }

    }
```

Here list1 is the column name and list is the table name

I placed a breakpoint and executed the code. It showed an exception ( Cannot delete Task`1: it has no PK) I think PK is column name in the exception once check the below code from sqlite class where the exception triggered

```
public int Delete (object objectToDelete)
    {
        var map = GetMapping (objectToDelete.GetType ());
        var pk = map.PK;
        if (pk == null) {
            throw new NotSupportedException ("Cannot delete " + map.TableName + ": it has no PK");
        }
        var q = string.Format ("delete from \"{0}\" where \"{1}\" = ?", map.TableName, pk.Name);
        return Execute (q, pk.GetValue (objectToDelete));
    }
```

Comment: PK means Primary Key

Comment: How to delete the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sql query.
When you assign (list_view.Selecteditem) in the query the database cannot identify the selected value because the statement selecteditem is familiar to multiple items in the list. So first store the selected item and pass it in the query.

```
private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";

        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        if (list_view.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            list k = (list)list_view.SelectedItem;
           await con.QueryAsync<list>("delete from list where list1='" + k.list1 + "'");

            update();
        }
 public async void update()
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        list_view.ItemsSource = new List<list>();
        List<list> mylist = await con.QueryAsync<list>("select * from list");
        if (mylist.Count != 0)
        {
            list_view.ItemsSource = mylist;
            list_view.DisplayMemberPath = "list1";
        }

    }
```